# How to find links to baselines in DOORS using DXL

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

For a given object, how do I find links to baselined modules? The code below only seemed to work on links to "Current" working versions of modules.

```
Link lnk
for lnk in (current Object) -> "*" do 
{
    print "Link found"
}
```

Thanks,
Phil

Edit:Added markup for code block -Jaambageek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, and don't worry this is not easy to find in the DXL Help either.

```
Link lnk
for lnk in all (current Object) -> "*" do 
{
    print "Link found"
}
```

The only word I added is `all`. That allows it to find versioned links. You can search Versioned Links in the DXL Help and you should find it.